# Variance of linear combination of random variables

Tags: self-study, variance

Let $X_1, X_2,...,X_{2n}$ be random variables such that $V(X_i)=4, i=1,2,...,2n$ and $Cov(X_i, X_j)=3, 1\leq i\neq j\leq 2n$. Then find

$V(X_1-X_2+X_3-X_4+...+X_{2n-1}-X_{2n})$.

I know that

> $V(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}a_iX_i)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{a_i}^2V(X_i)+2\times\sum\limits_{i,j(i\neq j)=1}^{n}a_ia_jCov(X_i,X_j)$

So, for this problem,

$V(X_1-X_2+X_3-X_4+...+X_{2n-1}-X_{2n})$

$=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2n}V(X_i)+2\times\sum\limits_{i,j(i\neq j)=1}^{2n}a_ia_jCov(X_i,X_j)$

$=8n+2\times\sum\limits_{i,j(i\neq j)=1}^{2n}a_ia_jCov(X_i,X_j)$

But I cannot calculate the $\sum\limits_{i,j(i\neq j)=1}^{2n}a_ia_jCov(X_i,X_j)$ part.

Please anyone help me solve the above problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What’s causing the trouble? What specifically are you struggling to calculate? It may be easier to set $k=2n$, as I don’t see you use $n$ anywhere except as $2n$.

Comment: @Dave I am struggling to calculate the sign of the 'Sum of Covariance' part, whether it will be positive or negative is my problem.

Comment: I think you will figure out the pattern if you start working it out for $n=1,2,3,...$ and then maybe prove it by induction. And forget what I said about $k$. I see now that there is a pattern of alternating signs.

Comment: Your assumptions allow you to factor the constant value $3=\operatorname{Cov}(X_i,X_j)$ out of the sum, leaving you just to do the arithmetic with the $a_ia_j.$